# How do I upload a file(picture) from android and save to the blobstore using GAE and google endpoints?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, blobstore

Sorry if this is a little general. Hopfully I can get pointed in the correct direction.

I have an android app that includes instant messaging. I want to add the functionality to send photos in messages as well. My backend is built on GAE and cloud endpoints and is written in Java.

So far, I've looked into google cloud storage, the blobstore, java servlet pages, etc. But a clear solution (or example using endpoints) has been impossible to find.

So, as the question states, how can I send and serve images from the blobstore using android and GAE endpoint backend?

Edit: This question is only regarding the back end. In android, I can do the http post easily enough. I'm just lost when it comes to doing this in endpoints

Comment: did you try this? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob

Comment: that appears to be a servlet and not an endpoint

Comment: you mean there is no way to use servlets and standard services in app with endpoints? i thought endpoints is just a nice tool to use in addition to standard webapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using a simple HTTP POST to handler for image upload?

When I use the blobstore I typically have a pair of handlers one for uploading and one for serving images.

So, in your case I'll rather do a post to a URL sending the image file and some parameter than can link it to the proper place in the datastore (i.e. user ID).

Then, using endpoints I'll have the same linking key and display the image using the serving handler with the given parameter.

Comment: Probably because I've been staring at my computer for 4 days trying to get this working and beyond exhausted, but I have no idea what that means. can you explain it like I'm 5? :D

Comment: Take a look at my longer answer to a similar post using only web: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409611/how-to-display-images-on-html-page-from-python-jinja/30448704#30448704 You'll need to have a pair of handlers for uploading and serving blobs (file pictures in the blobstore). In this case imagine your endpoint sends the parameter "id" I use in the downloading handler.

Comment: oh god, I'd have to adapt it from python. I also don't see it using getServingUrl(options) either. so I don't think it is what I'm looking for. :(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approach to implement what you require:

- Pass the image data as base64 encoded text from your client.
- On the server side, you can extract out the image content and then use one of many options that are available, which include Blobstore, Google Cloud Storage, etc. I suggest that you go with Google Cloud Storage because that is the recommended approach. If you prefer the Datastore, keep in mind that the data is limited to 1 MB in size, so you might hit that limit depending on the size of images that you are dealing with.
- A SO question and answer here contains lot of relevant code that you could utilize: [Sending images as a base64 string to a google cloud endpoint from cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228240/sending-images-as-a-base64-string-to-a-google-cloud-endpoint-from-cms)

Comment: Sounds good to me. Since we are converting the file to a byte array, which is essentially a String obejct now, won't size be an problem? i think java arrays (and by extension, Strings) have a 32kb max size. Since front end (android and doing the toByte encoding) and backend (receiving and storing/serving) are both in java, doesnt this raise an issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using endpoints you can follow @Romin 's suggestion and send the images as Base64 or upload your images in 2 steps using the blobstore/GCS service, first get the Upload URL (via endpoints) and then post your image to that URL.